# PHP broken timezone "echo"

Tags: php, html, arrays, timezone, echo

I'm working on a CMS. One of the options of the installation process is choosing the timezone.

The default value that displays is `America/Chicago`. There's a list of about 50+ cities that lets the user choose their location. The order of the cities doesn't matter because the server will list them alphabetically, with the default at the top. PHP writes the `options` for the timezones using `$TimezoneList` and `$SelectTZ` as seen below:

```
print $ServerTimezone;
```

and

```
foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo '<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>';}
```

But for some reason, the PHP doesn't write the variables correctly. The drop down list, when clicked, should display:

```
America/Chicago
Asia/Baku
America/Anchorage
America/Denver
Europe/Rome
Europe/Vienna
Pacific/Midway
```

The HTML source code display showing:

```
<option selected="selected" value="America/Chicago">America/Chicago</option>
<option value="Asia/Baku">Asia/Baku</option>
<option value="America/Anchorage">America/Anchorage</option>
(On and on and on....)
```

But instead the drop down list, when clicked, it displays `$SelectTZ`:

```
America/Chicago
$SelectTZ
$SelectTZ
$SelectTZ
$SelectTZ
$SelectTZ
$SelectTZ
```

The HTML source code display showing:

```
<option selected="selected" value="America/Chicago">America/Chicago</option>
<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>
<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>
(On and on and on....)
```

What is going on here? I'd like some help getting this fixed.

#### PHP/HTML from the CMS:

```
<?php
 $ServerTimezone = "America/Chicago";
 $TimezoneList = array (
  'Pacific/Midway',
  'America/Anchorage',
  'America/Chicago',
  'America/Denver',
  'Europe/Rome',
  'Europe/Vienna',
  'Asia/Baku'
 );
 // Sorts by the area/city name.
 sort ($TimezoneList);
?>
<form>
 <div>
  <label for="Timezone">What Is Your Timezone?</label>
  <select id="Timezone">
   <option selected="selected" value="<?php print $ServerTimezone; ?>"><?php print $ServerTimezone; ?></option>
<?php foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo '<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>';} ?>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
<?php ?>
```

Comment: Use double quotes instead? http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double Or heredoc. Or concatenate.

Comment: Try using double quotes instead of a single quote in your option set. Single quotes doesn't allow you to insert variables into your string. Example: `echo "<option value='$SelectTZ'>$SelectTZ</option>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, you can write variables in strings like this :

```
echo 'Hello '.$world; // Using single quotes
```

or

```
echo "Hello $world"; // Using double quotes
```

Also, in the case you need to get an array's value, you need to write it like this :

```
echo "Hello {$world['key']}";
```

This is the problem in your code. You'll need to replace

```
<?php foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo '<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>';} ?>
```

to

```
<?php foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo "<option value=\"$SelectTZ\">$SelectTZ</option>";} ?>
```

or

```
<?php foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo '<option value="'.$SelectTZ.'">'.$SelectTZ.'</option>';} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the last option. To quote Zelda, "You are great. You have an amazing wisdom and power."

Comment: I like when people quote Zelda @cdn

Answer (score 1):

When echoing with single quotes the variables inside the string aren't processed.

Change

```
foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo '<option value="$SelectTZ">$SelectTZ</option>';}
```

To

```
foreach ($TimezoneList as $SelectTZ) {echo "<option value=\"$SelectTZ\">$SelectTZ</option>";}
```

(Note the double quotes)

Comment: I tried this but the cities/counties would display and the source code displayed everything like `africa&ciaro&eruope&rome&asia&japan`.

Comment: Huh? Didn't get it. Changing the quotes should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<option value="'.$SelectTZ.'">'.$SelectTZ.'</option>';}
```

Try this..... Hope you will get it right.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to put detail next time.

Comment: You can edit your answer (bottom left) to update it accordingly, try it out! :)